# Pixastic doesn't work properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, pixastic

I'm using the [Pixastic](http://pixastic.com) javascript library to make several images on a webpage grayscale. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. Sometimes it makes a few random images grayscale, and sometimes it doesn't do anything at all.

Here's a test page to demonstrate the problem: http://www.edwards.nl/new/test.html

I'm using Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OSX Lion.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I couldn't find a solution anywhere yet.

Edit: It appears that the canvas elements are created, but the grayscaling part doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine in Safari 5.1 on Windows.  Do you get any error messages in the developer console?

Comment: Thanks for checking. Actually i get this: "GET http:/ bad URL"

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have a Mac on hand - so I can't help further. That is an interesting error, though, considering there are no absolute URLs in the code. I suspect this is a bug on the Mac version of Safari.  Perhaps somebody here with a Mac can confirm it.

Comment: I am experiencing this with Safari 5.1.2 on MAC 10.6.8

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this, so in the end i used PHP to create grayscale versions of the images with filenames like "bw_filename.jpg". The PHP script is only called when the grayscale version of the image doesn't exist yet.